# Create dynamically different (UIViewcontroller) instance names in for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I want to create an array of `ViewControllers` of my class `SlideViewController` and loop through them to assign different variable names to it or loop through the list and dynamically assign different names to my `SlideViewController` with array index appending like below:

```
for (int i=0; i<[_jsonArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = _jsonArray[i];

    SlideViewController *firstViewController = [[SlideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlideView" bundle:nil];

    //i want to do like this --- SlideViewController *firstViewController[i] = [[SlideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlideView" bundle:nil]; 

    NSLog(@"weekly Question.... %@",[dict objectForKey:@"weeklyquestion"]);

    firstViewController.question.text = [dict objectForKey:@"weeklyquestion"];

    [stepsArray addObject:firstViewController];
}

JJGMPageViewController *pageViewController = [[JJGMPageViewController alloc] init];

pageViewController.delegate = self;

[pageViewController addViewControllers:stepsArray];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above is not assigning the question to my    `firstViewController.question.text` and it's overwriting same instance.

Comment: You already have your view controllers in an array and you can access them through an index: `stepsArray[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see on this line, `firstViewController.question.text = [dict objectForKey:@"weeklyquestion"];`, you're either setting your UILabel or UITextView's text property. However, neither UILabel or UITextView may be initialized at that state.

So instead, declare an `NSString` property in your `SlideViewController` and set its value in your `for` loop. Then in your `SlideViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, set that `NSString` to your label's or textview's `text` property.